# How to add active class in a menu navbar with dropdown using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and I want to do is when one of the content of a dropdown is selected, the dropdown button (.dropbtn) will be highlighted.

here's my code in my master page:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="scroll active"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/index.aspx ") %>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/history.aspx ") %>">History</a>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" id="dropwebprog" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/mainspecies.aspx ") %>">Species</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="padding:0px;">
        <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/Species/1.aspx ") %>">1</a>
        <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/Species/2.aspx ") %>">2s</a>
        <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/Species/3.aspx ") %>">3</a>
        <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(" ~/Species/4.aspx ") %>">4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my js

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var substr = url.split('/');
    var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
    $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav li a').each(function() {
       if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
         $(this).parent().addClass('active');
       }
    });
  });
< /script>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your css and some working examples, the snippets you've provided don't work.

Comment: But this code work and adds the `active` class to selected `urlaspx` ... and if not, what does not work?

Comment: it doesn't work when i am in one of the selected dropdown contents.